# Comparing a string with an arrays.xml?

Tags: android, xml, arrays, compare

I want to compare a string with a country name obtain of a geocoder location, something like "france", "germany", "spain", etc. I don't know how I can do a search in this file to know if the string is in the arrays.xml or not.

I let you the arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="ntpGlobalServers_array">
        <item>Global</item>
        <item>Europe</item>
        <item>Asia</item>
        <item>Oceania</item>
        <item>North America</item>
        <item>South America</item>
        <item>Africa</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpEuropeServers_array">
        <item>Austria</item>
        <item>Switzerland</item>
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>Denmark</item>
        <item>Spain</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Luxembourg</item>
        <item>Netherlands</item>
        <item>Norway</item>
        <item>Poland</item>
        <item>Sweden</item>
        <item>Slovenia</item>
        <item>United Kingdom</item>
        <item>Finland</item>
        <item>Ireland</item>
        <item>Russian Federation</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Portugal</item>
        <item>Greece</item>
        <item>Hungary</item>
        <item>Bulgaria</item>
        <item>Romania</item>
        <item>Czech Republic</item>
        <item>Yugoslavia</item>
        <item>Estonia</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Slovakia</item>
        <item>Ukraine</item>
        <item>Lithuania</item>
        <item>Macedonia</item>
        <item>Moldova</item>
        <item>Latvia</item>
        <item>Croatia</item>
        <item>Republic of Serbia</item>
        <item>Bosnia and Herzegovina</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpAsiaServers_array">
        <item>Philippines</item>
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>Turkey</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Hong Kong</item>
        <item>United Arab Emirates</item>
        <item>Japan</item>
        <item>Bangladesh</item>
        <item>Israel</item>
        <item>Korea</item>
        <item>Thailand</item>
        <item>Iran</item>
        <item>Taiwan</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>Vietnam</item>
        <item>Pakistan</item>
        <item>Oman</item>
        <item>Uzbekistan</item>
        <item>Sri Lanka</item>
        <item>Kyrgyzstan</item>
        <item>Cambodia</item>
        <item>Qatar</item>
        <item>Saudi Arabia</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpOceaniaServers_array">
        <item>Australia</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>New Caledonia</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpNorthAmericaServers_array">
        <item>Canada</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Mexico</item>
        <item>Guatemala</item>
        <item>Panama</item>
        <item>Bahamas</item>
        <item>Costa Rica</item>
        <item>El Salvador</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpSouthAmericaServers_array">
        <item>Brazil</item>
        <item>Chile</item>
        <item>Argentina</item>
        <item>Venezuela</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="ntpAfricaServers_array">
        <item>Tanzania</item>
        <item>South Africa</item>
        <item>Angola</item>
        <item>Madagascar</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrays);
```

and then looping through that doing your comparison?

Comment: I don't know that I could do that. Thanks.

The array type must be String[] ?? or another type?

Answer (score 2):

Get the country name obtain of a geocoder location and  compare this string with the Array of strings in your arrays.xml in a for loop and see if that string is present.something like

```
String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)
So you get the array-list as a String[] and then choose and find  string from   some_array[i] which matches to your string from geocoder location.
```